# How do i evaluate $ \bigtriangleup^{10}(1-ax)(1-bx^{2})(1-cx^{3})(1-dx^{4}) $

Tags: numerical-methods

How do i evaluate $ \bigtriangleup^{10}(1-ax)(1-bx^{2})(1-cx^{3})(1-dx^{4}) $

where $ \bigtriangleup$ is forward difference operator. Now to evaluate this is impossible almost using definition which is $ \bigtriangleup$f(x)=$f(x+h)-f(x)$, so there has to be some trick to do this which i am looking for

Thanks

Comment: It's $10! abcd$. Now try to figure out how did I compute it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, what you are planning to do, but if the differentiation is of order 10, you might want to check the maximum order of your polynomial.

Comment: @zhoraster So there was a trick huh

Comment: @Taylor Ted, no tricks. What is $\triangle^{10} x^k$ for $k=0,\dots,10$?

Comment: @zhoraster  i did that for k=1,2,3 but i am not able to generalise for k

Comment: @Taylor Ted, what did you get for $k=1,2,3$?

Comment: @zhoraster Fro k=1 it is h, for k=2 it is $h^2 +2xh$, for k=3 it is $h^3 + 3x^2h+3xh^2$

Comment: @Taylor Ted, let $h=1$, this does not matter. What you wrote is $\Delta^1$, not $\Delta^{10}$

Comment: @zhoraster okay my bad. Now for $k=1$ i get $h$, for $k=2$ i get $3h^2$, for $k=3$ i get $13h^3$

Comment: @Taylor Ted, wrong. What is $\Delta g$ for constant $g$?

Comment: @zhoraster it is g itself

Comment: @zhoraster can you please post how you got your answer, its correct

Comment: @Taylor Ted, no. Write by definition. Hint: finite difference is kind of discrete derivative. And derivative of a constant is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: I would first prove two generally useful facts about $\Delta$.

- Prove that $$\Delta^k(x^n)=\begin{cases}
  0,&\text{if }k>n\\
  n^{\underline k},&\text{if }k\le n\;,
  \end{cases}$$ where $x^{\underline k}$ is the falling factorial, defined as $$x^{\underline k}=\underbrace{x(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)}_{k\text{ factors}}\;.$$ In particular, note that $n^{\underline n}=n!$.
- Prove that $\Delta$ is a linear operator: $\Delta\big(af(x)+bg(x)\big)=a\Delta\big(f(x)\big)+b\Delta\big(g(x)\big)$ for functions $f$ and $g$ and constants $a$ and $b$.

Now observe that once it’s been multiplied out, $(1-ax)(1-bx^2)(1-cx^3)(1-dx^4)$ is a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $10$; why?

The second result above says that you can evaluate $\Delta^{10}\big(p(x)\big)$ one term at a time, just as you might differentiate it one term at a time. And the first result above lets you do those individual evaluations very easily.

Answer (score 0):

The  highest term that survives after $\bigtriangleup^1,$ 
$$abcd\cdot10\{(x+1)^{10}-x^{10}\}=abcd\cdot10\cdot x^9$$

The highest term that survives after $\bigtriangleup^9,$   $$abcd\cdot\prod_{r=0}^8(10-r)\cdot x$$